# Facebook sdk get users phone number or Address?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I think i dug through the whole facebook sdk documentation but can't seem to find the way to get the users Phone number or Address. Is this feature removed, as of spoken in [this thread](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/) where it's suggested it will be re-enabled in a few weeks (2011).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This information is not available via the Facebook APIs and will not be added anytime soon. If you want this information from the user you should prompt them for it after they have logged into your application using Facebook.

Here's a link to Facebook's APIs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

You can use the graph API explorer to gain a clearer understanding of what information is and isn't available.

Comment: Seems, its still removed, no way to get phone.